# My neural network does not recognize the last kind of data from the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

Let's start with the fact that I'm making my own neural network for recognizing gestures. It recognizes gestures based on the coordinates of the reference hand. In the dataset, I have 6 types of gestures numbered from 0 to 5. When I trained the neural network and test it, it recognizes all gestures except the 5th gesture, regardless of how unique it is. How can I fix this? Here is my creating nn code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense

df_train = pd.read_csv('train_dataset.csv')

x_train = df_train.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y_train = df_train['y']

x_train = x_train / 640

y_train_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 6)

model = keras.models.Sequential([Dense(256, input_shape=(42,), activation='relu'),
                                Dense(524, activation='relu'),
                                Dense(1048, activation='relu'),
                                Dense(6, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train_cat, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3)

model.save("gestures_model.h5")
```

Here is an example of data:

```
x11,x21,x12,x22,x13,x23,x14,x24,x15,x25,x16,x26,x17,x27,x18,x28,x19,x29,x110,x210,x111,x211,x112,x212,x113,x213,114,214,115,x215,x116,x216,x117,x217,x118,x218,x119,x219,x120,x220,x121,x221,y

301,281,324,273,345,256,361,244,373,238,324,223,326,198,325,182,324,168,308,223,307,212,309,235,309,247,293,227,291,218,296,239,297,250,278,233,276,221,281,235,284,244,0
135,151,187,167,234,191,279,201,317,200,205,242,213,322,216,365,215,398,166,249,174,319,177,297,176,268,128,249,138,313,140,291,138,265,92,248,102,304,105,284,103,261,1
312,280,317,267,315,253,315,242,317,233,300,235,322,230,323,241,318,250,298,234,322,229,323,242,319,250,299,234,322,229,323,240,319,248,301,235,320,231,322,239,318,245,5
```

And here is an example of using the nn:

```
gest_map = {
    0: "up",
    1: "down",
    2: "right",
    3: "left",
    4: "forward",
    5: "back"
}

def mapper(val):
    return gest_map[val]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df / 640
pred = model.predict(df)
move_code = np.argmax(pred[0])
user_move_name = mapper(move_code)
print(user_move_name)
```

Comment: Could you add the metrics of the model evaluation? It may well be due to a unbalanced dataset if that class is not common .Please show a confusion matrix and other metrics if you can, it could help identify the problem.

Comment: 394/394 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 2.5559 - accuracy: 0.8321
[2.5558645725250244, 0.8321428298950195]

Comment: Put the confusion matrix to evaluate the model by classes. Something like this should suffy: "matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1))"

Comment: I have written this: `import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.ops.confusion_matrix import confusion_matrix

model = keras.models.load_model("gestures_model.h5")

df_test = pd.read_csv('train_dataset.csv')

x_test = df_test.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y_test = df_test['y']

x_test = x_test / 640

predicted = model.predict(x_test)

matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test.argmax(axis=1), predicted.argmax(axis=1))
print(matrix)`

Comment: But I get it: `ValueError: axis must be fewer than the number of dimensions (1)`

Comment: What I need to do?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, I just haven’t entered my code for a very long time and now I’m trying to fix it.

Comment: in your case i think it may be because in y_test you have only 1 column, so there should not be an argmax in it. Try confusion_matrix(y_test, np.argmax(predicted[0]))

Comment: `tf.Tensor(
[[2100    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 2100    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0 2100    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 2100    0    0]
 [  15    0    0    0 2085    0]
 [ 317    0 1105  373  305    0]], shape=(6, 6), dtype=int32)`

Comment: From this output you can see that none of the elements classified like 5 are selected as such. You have to rethink your architecture or review where that data is not being trained.

Comment: And can I create another class that will not be used so that the fifth gesture is recognized?

Comment: I still have a problem with the neural network. It turned out that the last two gestures, regardless of their uniqueness, are not recognized at all.

Comment: I also changed the data architecture because it turned out that my data standardization was not correct.